# Preemption to avoid deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock

I understand the process of using preemption to avoid deadlocks but I'm having a hard time trying to put it in code.

My understanding of preemption to avoid deadlock using **threads t1, t2** and **resources** **w, x, y** is:

`thread t1 -> has resource X. request resource W`

`thread t2 -> has resources W, Y. request resource X`

`t1 checks if resource W is free. if it's not free, don't acquire resource X or release it.`

`t2 executes. Releases resources W, Y, X`

`t1 executes`

How should I go about implementing something like I described above in c++? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

One way is through numbering the resources (look at 7.4.4 [here](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/7_Deadlocks.html)):

```
w = 1
y = 2
x = 3
```

Then a simple rule: A thread can get a resource only in increasing order.

> In other words, in order to request resource Rj, a process must first release all Ri such that i >= j.

thread `t1` -> has resource `X` (value is 3). request resource `W` (value is 1)  ==> it needs to release `X` first

thread `t2` -> has resources `W` (value is 1), `Y` (value is 2). request resource `X` (value is 3) ==> gets it right after `t1` released it